# How to split config section in multiple files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a utility application which allows user to import/export data from various databases. Each new task is added by adding a custom config section in app.config as shown below. Over the time the app.config file has grown very large & to keep things simple, I wanted user to be able to add new task in separate file. I have read options where `appSettings` or `connectionString` settings can be moved to different config file by specifying `configSource` attribute. Is it possible to do the same for custom sections?

Example of custom section which I use internally for task configuration.

```
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="tasks">
      <sectionGroup name="ImportData">
        <section name="transferType" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
        <section name="srcConnectionString" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
        <section name="srcProcedure" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
        <section name="destConnectionString" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
        <section name="destTable" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
```

```
  <tasks>
    <ImportData>
      <transferType>
        <add key="transferType" value="database" />
      </transferType>
      <srcConnectionString>
        <add key="srcConnectionString" value="sourceDB" />
      </srcConnectionString>
      <srcProcedure>
        <add key="srcProcedure" value="sourceProcedureName" />
      </srcProcedure>
      <destConnectionString>
        <add key="destConnectionString" value="destConnection" />
      </destConnectionString>
      <destTable>
        <add key="destTable" value="TableName" />
      </destTable>
    </ImportData>
  </tasks>
```

The section value is read like

```
NameValueCollection transferSection = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ImportData/transferType");
```

How to add new sections in separate file & still continue to be able read the same way.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121135/is-it-possible-to-override-both-appsettings-and-connectionstrings-in-a-local-con?rq=1

Comment: @Bombinosh yes, I saw that already. The connectionStrings has configSource attribute where they have specified the external file. I wanted same with Sections

Comment: You can do the same for custom section https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713147/custom-configurationsection-to-external-config

Comment: @Bombinosh thanks for sharing the link. I think I can make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't feasible out of the box according to .NET's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/section-element).

An alternative would be to restructure your web.config:

```xml
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="tasks">
        <section name="import" />
        <section name="export" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<tasks>
    <import configSource="import.config" />
    <export configSource="export.config" />
</tasks>
```

You can then add your custom import/export tasks in those external files.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to work it around. Since its a old utility, I would not want to have separate config file for each task, ( I have 45 so far & more to come). I wanted to break it such a way to have max 10 tasks in one config file, making it manageable